# Ehcache Element lifetime in cache

Tags: spring, caching, ehcache

Image making a Spring service, in the following manner:

```
+--------+           +---------+             +---------+
|Backend | --------- | My      | ----------- | Clients |
|service |           | service |             |         |
+--------+           +---------+             +---------+
```

In order not to make too much requests to the backend, I use Ehcache.
Imagine that my service is a sports portal, and I cache the results so that when a client requests them, I return the cache, if there's no cache, I fetch the info from backend, put it in cache, and then return it to the client.

Now, If I have these parameters set

```
long timeToLiveSeconds
long timeToIdleSeconds
```

and the clients make requests too often, the `timeToIdleSeconds` won't expire, but the `timeToLiveSeconds` will expire anyway and the element will be removed from the cache in which I've put it, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are right.

For example:

`timeToIdleSeconds = 30`: if the cached object was not requested during that 30 seconds, it expires => last access time counts

`timeToLiveSeconds = 60`: after 60 seconds the cached object will expire - no matter how often it was requested or requested at all => creation time counts

From the docs (older version 1.4):

> `timeToIdleSeconds`:
>   Sets the time to idle for an element before it expires.
>   i.e. The maximum amount of time between accesses before an element expires
>   Is only used if the element is not eternal.
>   Optional attribute. A value of 0 means that an Element can idle for infinity.
>   The default value is 0.
>
> `timeToLiveSeconds`:
>   Sets the time to live for an element before it expires.
>   i.e. The maximum time between creation time and when an element expires.
>   Is only used if the element is not eternal.
>   Optional attribute. A value of 0 means that and Element can live for infinity.
>   The default value is 0.

Answer (score 0):

In case you set both, the `expirationTime` will be `Math.min(ttlExpiry, ttiExpiry)`, where

```
ttlExpiry = creationTime + timeToLive
ttiExpiry = mostRecentTime + timeToIdle
```

Full source code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache-core/2.5.0/net/sf/ehcache/Element.java#Element.getExpirationTime%28%29).